# largest volume tetrahedron in a convex polyhedron

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, geometry, convex-polygon

Given a convex polyhedron, I need to find a faster algorithm for the maximum volume tetrahedron inscribed in it. I could only think of the brute force solution of O(n^4). I was thinking if we can find the farthest vertex in convex polyhedron from a triangle formed using 3 vertices of polyhedron in less than O(n) time using some preprocessing.The volume of this tetrahedron will be maximum with this triangle base (volume of tetrahedron is 1/3*base area*height) and doing this for all triangle will give me maximum volume tetrahedron in less than O(n^4).

Comment: You could probably build some acceleration data structure (bounding volume hierarchies or octrees sound reasonable) to get down to `O(log n)`. Btw, the 2d case seems to be quite well-analyzed (see e.g. [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.11035.pdf)). Maybe you can extract some ideas from there.

Comment: I have read that [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.11035.pdf) but got no idea about the problem in 3D. Could you tell me about the preprocessing I can do?

Comment: I meant to build an e.g. BVH from the points, which can answer the query "what other point is the farthest from point x" more efficiently than a linear search. Usually, they are used for closest point search, but some of them also allow farthest point searches.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect this probabilistic algorithm to give a tetrahedron with a volume that is at least close to the largest possible value with a high probability:

1. choose any three (pairwise different) vertices `A,B,C` from the polyhedron
2. choose a point `D` from the polyhedron which maximizes the volume of the tetrahedron `ABCD`.
3. choose a point `A'` from the polyhedron which maximizes the volume of the tetrahedron `A'BCD`
4. choose a point `B'` from the polyhedron which maximizes the volume of the tetrahedron `A'B'CD`
5. choose a point `C'` from the polyhedron which maximizes the volume of the tetrahedron `A'B'C'D`
6. if `A==A'` and `B==B'` and `C==C'` stop with the answer `ABCD`.
7. set `A=A'`, `B=B'`, `C=C'` and continue at 2.

Clearly this algorithm terminates for any finite polyhedron and any initial choice of A,B,C. And if the polyhedron is not "too symmetric" the algorithm should terminate quickly (< `O(n^2)`).

Now running this algorithm several times (with different random choices of A,B,C at step 1.) and keeping the largest tetrahedron found so far will increase the probability of being close to or arriving at the maximal possible volume.

Comment: This is a probabilistic algorithm but I need a deterministic algorithm.